# Need export query rather than creating file for mysqldump without triggers

Tags: php, triggers, export, mysql

I have code as

```
$db_name = "db";
$outputfile = "/somewhere";
$new_db_name = 'newdb';

$cmd = 'mysqldump --skip-triggers %s > %s  2>&1';
$cmd = sprintf($cmd, escapeshellarg($db_name), escapeshellcmd($output_file));
exec($cmd, $output, $ret); 
if ($ret !=0 ) {
    //log error message in $output
}
```

Then to import:

```
$cmd = 'mysql --database=%s < %s 2>&1';
$cmd = sprintf($cmd, escapeshellarg($new_db_name), escapeshellcmd($output_file));
exec($cmd, $output, $ret); 
//etc.

unlink($outputfile);
```

But here what should i do to get the export query, rather than creating a file everytime?

> **EDITED:**
>
> IN THE RESPONSE OF REPLY OF MATT

- I am using Windows, will the code u have given work as I am not sure the code I already have will work in Windows as it seems to be linux commands?
- Its my need to script in PHP its the process which is going to be triggered when installing a component in joomla
- What is PIPE in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to do this in PHP? You can easily do this in a terminal with some basic piping (no need to create any files).

Two commands and you're done:

```
echo 'create database foo2' | mysql -uroot
mysqldump --skip-triggers -uroot foo | mysql -uroot foo2
```

This copies `foo` into new database `foo2`

Note that it *is* possible to [pipe in php](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) .. but .. really, you should just do this in shell (IMO).

**Edit:**

Oops, for some reason I thought you *wanted* triggers. Edited above to include `--skip-triggers`

**Edit 2:**

'Piping' refers to routing `stdout` and `stdin`.

Windows supports pipes. The above commands are working for me on Windows.

However, I am not able to get piping to work through PHP with Windows (at least not for `mysql`). It's like the streams from `proc_open` ignore my input.

So the alternative would be to take the commands I provided above, put them in a `.bat` file, and see if you can call that script via [`system()`](http://php.net/system)

**Final edit**:

You're going to need to do some research as I can't explain every small detail. Did you reference the `system()` documentation I pointed to? It lets you call system commands ..

My suggestion is you make a basic script, call it `bla.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo create database foo2 | mysql -uroot
mysqldump --skip-triggers -uroot foo | mysql -uroot foo2
```

If that's in the same folder as your script, then your script can do this:

```
<?php
system('cmd.exe /C ' . dirname(__FILE__).'\\bla.bat');
```

Viola. DB copied.

Comment: @Matt Don't mind, But everything sounds very sophisticated to me, Can u simplify

Comment: Nice one, exactly what I was looking for :o)